# How to get a matrix of correlations with cor() function?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I am using base package of R in windows system.

I have two matrices which have one column of numeric values. Both matrices are of same size.

I am using a following code

```
c<-cor(x,y)
```

where `x`,`y` are matrices with size 10*1 but `c` is of size 1*1

The output is only a single value. When I  use the `cor` function it should give an output at least equal to the size of the matrix right?

if I use `summary(c)` my output should be something like this:

```
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -0.2110 -0.0500  0.0946  0.1250  0.2680  0.7630
```

but I am getting:

```
 Min.   :0.06088  
 1st Qu.:0.06088  
 Median :0.06088  
 Mean   :0.06088  
 3rd Qu.:0.06088  
 Max.   :0.06088
```

Comment: 'cor' calculates the correlation coefficient which is a single number. Were you expecting it to do something else?

Comment: Maybe he wants a correlation matrix? 2x2?

Comment: I want an output which returns a vector of correlations for the values present in the matrix X and Y. I thought cor would give that output. But if it gives a single number, can you suggest me which would produce the vector of correlations

Answer (score 1):

You need to put X and Y in a data.frame or matrix for this to work. Here is a quick example

```
set.seed(4)  #so that we have the same random numbers
X<-rnorm(100)
Y<-rnorm(100)
W<-cor(data.frame(X,Y))
W

           X          Y
X  1.0000000 -0.1338078
Y -0.1338078  1.0000000

as.vector(W)
[1]  1.0000000 -0.1338078 -0.1338078  1.0000000
```

You can wrap the `cor` in `as.vector` to store it as a vector if you like.

Comment: But its not helping me to get an answer. I have a 2 Matices with same dimensions. When i perform the correlation. I need an output which has summary as summary(cr)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
## -0.2110 -0.0500  0.0946  0.1250  0.2680  0.7630
 and also Lenght(cr) should be equal to the no of rows in the matrix. For example if the Matrix X has 923 rows and one column. After correlation my length() function should give the length as 923. is it possible???/ If so let me know the approach

Comment: The `cor` function is not going to do that, unless I am missing something. Typically a correlation between two vectors is a single number even if the vectors have hundreds or millions of values. Are you sure that correlation is what you want? Or are X and Y lists of vectors?

Comment: "Write a function that takes a directory of data files and a threshold for complete cases and calculates the correlation between sulfate and nitrate for monitor locations where the number of completely observed cases (on all variables) is greater than the threshold. The function should return a vector of correlations for the monitors that meet the threshold requirement. If no monitors meet the threshold requirement, then the function should return a numeric vector of length 0."

Comment: This is the question and in the required output section is the sample output i have shown. I have read in all the files used the threshold and all correctly but output is nt matching as it is only one element(i.e corr(x,y)). So i dont know how can i achieve the output.

Comment: Sulfate and Nitrate are the variables inside the CSV files

Comment: Based on that I think you need to do a `cor` for each monitor that meets the requirements (I assume there are several, maybe one per .csv file), and put the results of each `cor` into a vector and do the `summary`. So you just need to the the `cor` repeatedly, each time you get a single number.

Comment: @GouthamGaddam: so put that task definition in your question details. People seem to be downvoting this one because they don't understand you're trying to something non-obvious and tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
    Firstly, according to assignment you should return a vector of correlations. Its length is equal to the number of monitors,meeting the threshold requirement.(number of complete cases is greater than the threshold value).
    Let **df** is a data.frame, which comprises data from all monitors, having number of complete cases greater than threshold(hope you can get this **df** by yourself and read.csv,rbind functions). So:
    Lets group this data frame by monitors ID:

```
df_gb<-group_by(df,ID)
```

Now we can calculate correlation between sulfate and nitrate fields and summarize it by ID and create new field(variable) **Cor** simultaneously:

```
dfsum<-summarize(df_gb,Cor=cor(sulfate,nitrate,use = "pairwise.complete.obs"))
```

Then we leave only **Cor** field in  **dfsum** data frame by:

```
dfsum<-select(dfsum,Cor)
```

Let's exclude NA results (because we don't see NA summary in example output of the function, need to be created,don't we?)

```
dfsum<-filter(dfsum,is.na(Cor)==FALSE)
```

Finally we should return numeric vector(according to assignment):

```
return(dfsum$Cor)
```

That's all and, please, **DON'T FORGET**

```
library(dplyr)
```

before using **group_by,select,filter** functions.